# MySQL: How to get the max of a sum column?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, max

So I have the following query ..

```
select rooms.id room_id, rooms.cnt, booked_dates.cnt, sum(booked_dates.cnt) 
from rooms 
LEFT JOIN booked_dates 
       on rooms.id = booked_dates.rid and 
          (booked_dates.start between '2013-05-06' and '2013-05-09')
where rooms.ht = 4 and rooms.id = 138 
group by booked_dates.start
```

which returns the following results ..

[image]

Now I need to group them results by the `room_id` and get the `max` number in the `sum(booked_dates.cnt)` column. So for the example it would be:

`138 | 20 | 4 | 12`

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I see a number of non-aggregated fields in that column list... are you sure that's what you mean?  Maybe I just don't understand that those `cnt` columns represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  rooms.id room_id, rooms.cnt, booked_dates.cnt, SUM(booked_dates.cnt) AS booked_sum
FROM    rooms 
LEFT JOIN
        booked_dates 
ON      rooms.id = booked_dates.rid
        AND (booked_dates.start between '2013-05-06' and '2013-05-09')
WHERE   rooms.ht = 4
        AND rooms.id = 138 
GROUP BY
        booked_dates.start
ORDER BY
        booked_sum DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a max() column:

```
select
    rooms.id room_id,
    rooms.cnt,
    booked_dates.cnt, 
    max(booked_dates.cnt) as max ,
    sum(booked_dates.cnt) as sum
from rooms 
LEFT JOIN booked_dates 
   on rooms.id = booked_dates.rid and 
      (booked_dates.start between '2013-05-06' and '2013-05-09')
where rooms.ht = 4 and rooms.id = 138 
group by 1, 2, 3
```

You had a bug in your group by clause - This query fixes that too (note that you may refer to columns by their *position*, rather than their expression, in group by clauses).